# Zero solution to a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A solution of a differential equation is different to zero if the initial value is different to zero.
This property is it true for all type of differential equation or just for the Bernoulli equation like $z'=z^{r}$, $r$ is a positive real?

Comment: Wait - if alrady the initial value is different to zero, how could the complete solution be zero?

Comment: What is the context of your problem?

Comment: I want  eliminate the zero solution , what I add like assumption to the differential equation? Is it sufficient to assume that $z(t{0})\neq 0$?

Answer (score 1):

Of course this is not true for all ODE. Take $x'=t$ with the solution $x=\frac12t^2$ for zero initial values.

---

But of course, if in an autonomous ODE $x'=f(x)$ you start at a fixed point $x(0)=x^*$, i.e., a root $f(x^*)=0$, then the solution is constant $x(t)=x^*$. With the Lipschitz condition this also is the only solution. Your question is about the special case $f(0)=0$.

---

To the special cases mentioned: $z'=z^r$ is unproblematic for $r\ge1$. For $0<r<1$ it is not Lipschitz in $z=0$. If at some point $z(t_1)\ne0$ the solution around this point can be found by separation, $z^{-r}z'=1$, $\frac1{1-r}z^{1-r}=t-c$, $$z(t)=((1-r)(t-c))^{\frac1{1-r}}.$$

If $c>0$, then the maximal solution for this starts with $z(t)=0$ on $t\in[0,c]$ and continues with this formula for $t>c$.

For $z'+z=z^r$, insert $z(t)=e^{-t}u(t)$ to get $$u'=e^tz^r=e^{(1-r)t}u^r$$ to find a similar equation to the above one.

Comment: I restrict the question to first order DOE of the types$z'=z^{r}$, and $z'+z=z^{r}$,$r$ is a positive real

Comment: This is not how you formulated your question.

Comment: For eliminate the zero solution ,is it sufficient to assume that $z(t{0})\neq 0$? or just $z(0)\neq 0$?

Comment: As the solution is continuous, any solution with $z(t)\ne 0$ for some $t$ can not be the zero solution, as it is non-zero over some non-trivial interval.

Comment: Then, there are two conditions
1) $z(t{0})\neq 0$.
2) $z(t)$ is a continuous function

Comment: A solution to a differential equation is, by definition, differentiable.

Comment: So, there remains only one condition.